# Timeline.js how to make dates in reverse order

Tags: javascript, php, timeline.js

Currently, our timeline order with `timeline.js` is: *"2020 -> 2021 -> 2022"*, but we need to do the opposite: *"2022 -> 2021 -> 2020"*. I didn't find any settings in the library itself. How can this be done?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/works/jquery.timeline.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('.timelineLight').timeline({
    openTriggerClass: '.trigger_open',
    itemMargin: 44,
    startItem: 'first',
})
```

[image]

Comment: Pelase share more details. Why did you tag this question with PHP, but haven't shared any such code?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't a supported feature, and likely never will be.

From Joe Germuska (Exec Director at Night Labs)

> "This is not a supported feature. Timeline's design reinforces the very strong assumption readers of left-to-right languages have that timelines should have the past on the left and the future on the right. Perhaps it should reverse this for right-to-left languages, but that is not a small task, and TimelineJS is not under active feature development at this time.  Sorry."

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the link below [Reversing The Timeline?](https://knightlab.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/211631846-Reversing-the-timeline-)  it is possible by using  "start_at_end".

`<script type="text/javascript"> var additionalOptions = { start_at_end: true, language: 'en', timenav_height: 250 }`